# How do you run a half float ONNX model using ONNXRuntime C API?

Tags: c++, c, onnx, onnxruntime

Since the C language doesn't have a half float implementation, how do you send data to the ONNXRuntime C API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's possibly an example you can follow linked from here: https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/1173#issuecomment-501088662

You can create a buffer to write the input data to using CreateTensorAsOrtValue, and access the buffer within the OrtValue using GetTensorMutableData.

ONNXRuntime is using Eigen to convert a float into the 16 bit value that you could write to that buffer.

```
uint16_t floatToHalf(float f) {
  return Eigen::half_impl::float_to_half_rtne(f).x;
}
```

Alternatively you could edit the model to add a Cast node from float32 to float16 so that the model takes float32 as input.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will try to add a Cast node. Can you perhaps point me to an example or a tutorial on how to edit ONNX models? Thank you.

Comment: Here's example python that shows adding a Cast node to replace an original graph input.

https://gist.github.com/skottmckay/32ea04dc0232c31d22a0eb80025e0dfe

Answer (score 1):

> the C language doesn't have a half float implementation

Yes, but there are language extensions and you can write your own library to handle the data.

So, for example there is `_Float16` type defined by ISO/IEC TS 18661-3:2015 supported by [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Half-Precision.html) on some architectures.

And you can write or [find a library](https://www.google.com/search?q=float+16+github+C) that will handle the half-floating point operations.

Comment: Yes, I can try to use an implementation from github. However if ONNXRuntime is already using some kind of half float implementation wouldn't it be simpler to use the implementation they are using? Due to poor ONNXRuntime documentation I'm not able to figure out how to do this.